# MultiLabelBinarizer() with inverse_transform()

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, labels

I have multilabel labels. Elements in a label mean voting. Here is how labels look:

```
array([[ 4,  0,  0,  1,  3,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  0,  0,  3,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  0,  0,  4,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0]])
```

And here is what I tried:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
nn = mlb.fit_transform(labels_train)
nn[:10]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And when I tried `inverse_transform()`:

```
zet = mlb.inverse_transform(nn)
zet[:10]
```

out:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (0, 1, 6),
 (0, 1, 3, 5),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 1, 9),
 (0, 1, 6),
 (0, 2, 8),
 (0, 10),
 (0, 10),
 (0, 4, 6)]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it showing unique values in ascending order?

Comment: Please don't cross-post exact duplicates. When I suggested you ask here, I meant the modeling question "how should I encode/model for this voting target." This question, about `MultiLabelBinarizer`, was suitable for SO, but the answer was simply "that's what `MultiLabelBinarizer` is supposed to do."

Answer (score 2):

This seems intuitive.

When we have a single-label response (Multi-Class setting), our response prior to encoding looks like:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
```

After encoding,it becomes

```
[[1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1]]
```

Indicating the presence of ith Class. But only one.
Similarly, in a multi-label setting-

Input should be - `[[1,2,5], [4,1], [2,3] [3], [5,4]]`

Encoded value   - `[[1,1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1,0], [0,1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1,1]]`

*Indicating the presence of (i,j,k)th Classes. Can be many*

There is no need to keep duplicate values in the data before encoding.
The inverse function will work in the same way.

> *The set of labels for each sample such that y[i] consists of classes_[j] for each yt[i, j] == 1.*

But if you try to transform again the o/p of inverse, you will get the same encoding.

```py
mlb.transform(zet)
```

> array([
>
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>
>    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
>
> [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>
>  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>
>  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
>
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
>
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

Comment: thanks for the answer. I upvoted